# fullcalendar with multiple resources populated from database

Tags: javascript, c#, fullcalendar

I have used free version of fullcalendar, now I need to to have multiple resources on it. is it possible to do that in free version of it? if yes does anyone have an example of it to be populated from the database? for mutiple resource should I use fullcalendar scheduler or the standard fullcaneldar does the job

Comment: Technically, what frameworks do you use for the front-end and the back-end?

Comment: @hotcakedev: MVC C# and javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a lack of experience in C#, but hopefully the following example using JavaScript would help you.

First, you can get all events from your multiple resources using the free version of fullcalendar.

Second, here's one of the fullcalendar example using multiple resources.

Please refer to the [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources) for more details.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEventsEl = document.getElementById('calendar-events');

    calendarEvents = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEventsEl, {
        headerToolbar: false,
        contentHeight: 300,
        initialView: 'listUpcoming',
        views: {
            listUpcoming: {
                type: 'listMonth',
                duration: { months: 2 },
            },
            listAll: {
                type: 'listYear',
                duration: { years: 1 },
            },
        },
        eventDidMount: function (arg) {
          ...
        },

        dayHeaderDidMount: function (arg) {
          ...
        },
        eventSources: [
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          // This is the approach how to get events from multiple resources
          {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/calendar/get_all_for_events_01/',
            extraParams: {
                get_type: 'upcoming',
                timezone: moment.tz.guess()
            }
          },
          {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/calendar/get_all_for_events_02/',
            extraParams: {
                get_type: 'all',
                timezone: moment.tz.guess()
            },
          }
        ],
        eventSourceSuccess: function (content, xhr) {
            ...
        },
```

Hope this would help.